# BlackBerry Email Responsive Queries

Tags: media-queries, html-email, blackberry-10, email-client

I'm creating an email template in MailChimp, and I have some responsive code that I want to work for the devices that support it (primarily iOS Mail and BlackBerry Mail apps).

While the template loads the responsive media queries correctly in the iOS Mail app, they don't appear to trigger within the BlackBerry Mail app. I am testing on both a BlackBerry Z10 and Q10 with the same up-to-date OS.

My media query looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
        #templateContainer {
            width: 100% !important;
        }       
        .globalLogo {
            width: 90% !important;
        }
        .logoBox {
            display: block !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }
        .imageBox {
            width: 100% !important;
            display: block !important;
            height: 40px !important;
            border-left: none !important;
        }
        .emailTitle {
            text-align: center !important;
        }
        #title {
            border-top: 3px solid #FFF !important;
            width: 100% !important;
            display: table !important;
        }
        .topImageRow {
            display: none !important;
        }
        .tableofcontents {
            margin:0 0 30px 0 !important;
            list-style: outside !important;
            width: 90% !important;
        }
  }
```

I've also added the following viewport meta tag to the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I've experimented with max-width instead of max-device-width, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. I've also tried 800px instead of 600px, and removing the "only screen and" from the media query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final Answer:

Send it to a different email account domain. It can sometimes be the security filters at your workplace, so if you're sending it to you@yourwork.com, try hooking up you@yourotheremail.com to your blackberry and checking it there.

---

Original:

Not really a definitive answer, but hopefully this will get you closer...

Create a really easy media query to trigger (something like max-width:99999px;) and change the color or something really noticeable. Does it work at all?

If it is triggering, step your way down until it stops. If you can't get it to trigger at 99999px, it doesn't support media queries, even though [the support charts](http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2012/10/responsive-email-support/) suggest it does.

Sometimes your server can strip the media queries, so try testing it on different domain also, particularly if you have any sort of corporate server or software.

Another thing you could do is try and view the output code to see if your CSS is still intact. Not sure how to view this on a Blackberry though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so I did some testing along those lines and experimented with different media queries (all vs only screen, max-width vs max-device-width) all with the value at 9999px, and while it worked on the iOS Mail app, it did nothing to the BB10 devices.

I even tried changing the actual positioning of where the media query is called, but that also didn't seem to have an effect.

Is it possible that MailChimp is doing something that makes the query unreadable by BlackBerry 10 devices?

Comment: Mailchimp wouldn't, unless there is a setting on the css inliner to remove your `<style>`, and even then I give them too much credit to make the mistake of also removing media queries (at lease by default). It should work within the `<style>` tag in the header of the html. Did you try sending it to a different email account domain? It can sometimes be the security filters at your workplace, so if you're sending it to you@yourwork.com, try hooking up you@yourotheremail.com to your blackberry and checking it there.

Comment: Wow I think that might have been the issue. We tried on a personal BlackBerry on a private email account and it worked perfectly. Any idea where these security filters are being applied? Also if you want to update your answer I'll mark it as correct, thanks so much for the help troubleshooting!

Comment: @DaveHunt You're welcome. Not sure what software it is, but it seems to be a more common issue than most people think. Updated answer.